# How to navigate around a linked list?

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list

So let's say I have 3 nodes in my linked lists, each with a first name in it.  The list is supposed to be ordered alphabetically.  I need to navigate with pointers

I have a .h interface and a .c file implementation, so you can assume anything prototyped int he List.c file is not in the header file.

Let me explain what's going on logically, to make my code a bit easier to understand.  ListP is a pointer to struct List that has simple attributes like logical size, physical size and a pointer to the head of the linked list.  The character strings are typedefd as ListItemP for easy reconstruction to an integer linked list etc if need be.

List.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "List.h"

typedef struct Entry *EntryP;

EntryP newEntry(ListItemP thisItem);

struct List
{
    int sizeL;
    int sizeP;
    ListItemP head;
};

struct Entry
{
    ListItemP content;
    struct Entry *next;
};

ListP newList()
{
    ListP thisList = (ListP) malloc(sizeof(ListP));
    thisList->head = 0x00;
    thisList->sizeL = 0;
    thisList->sizeP = 0;
    return thisList;
}

void insertItemList(ListP thisList, ListItemP thisItem)
{
    EntryP thisEntry = newEntry(thisItem);
    thisEntry->content = thisItem;

    // Make a conditional for the first condition (no items in list)
    if ((thisList->head == 0x00) || (strcmp(thisItem, thisList->head) < 0)) {
        thisList->head = thisEntry->content;
        thisEntry->next = 0x00;
    }
   // The other conditional are what I don't understand, how to put go through
      navigate through the list via pointers and such.

    thisList->sizeL++;
    thisList->sizeP++;
}

void displayList(ListP thisList)
{
    printf("First Item: %s\n",thisList->head);
}

/*
 * Not in the interface
 */
EntryP newEntry(ListItemP thisItem)
{
    EntryP thisEntry = (EntryP) malloc(sizeof(EntryP));
    thisEntry->content = thisItem;
    thisEntry->next = NULL;
    return thisEntry;
}
```

I would post my main.c (or tester.c or whatever you want to call it) but I don't really think its going to help at all, all the linked list navigation is going to occur in the List.c file.

So my question is this, assuming I have 3 or 4 or however many nodes, how can I navigate around them so I can do things like string compares and yadda yadda in order to place new strings in the linked list in alphabetical order.

Thank you!

Comment: 0) `TypeP var = malloc(sizeof(*var));`